# Differences between angle brackets and double quotation marks in C++ include

Tags: c++, include, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

This is to do with the difference between using angle brackets and quotation marks to include files in C++, i.e.:

```
#include "mypath/myfile"
```

vs

```
#include <mypath/myfile>
```

I understand that the way the compiler searches for the files differs in each case (from [here](http://objectmix.com/c/39606-include-angle-brackets-versus-quotes.html)). However, does it affect the *way* the files are included? Are the same things (definitions, templates etc.) included in each case?